# Show banner after Starting the Google SDK

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, admob, ads

I try to implement the UMP SDK in a SwiftUI app. After adding the code of Google, the code will run Google Mobile Ads SDK and start to request an interstitialAd. How could I load a banner ad in stead of a InterstitialAd.

This is the code:

```
private func startGoogleMobileAdsSDK() {
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  guard !self.isMobileAdsStartCalled else { return }

  self.isMobileAdsStartCalled = true

  // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
  GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start()

  **// TODO: Request an ad.
  // <<<Load a BANNER here>>>**
 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is a view that represents banner ads called `GADBannerView`. After `GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start()` you can directly set `GADBannerView` an `adUnitId` to your bannerID which was created on the admob page.

However, this view is from UIKit so you need to adapt to SwiftUI. This [document](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/swiftui) quite good, you should take a look and follow.